# Security Center won't start after a malware attack

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware

Today, I got a virus/malware on my computer.  I first scan with my antivirus/malwarebytes/superantispyware to clean it.  I ended up cleaning all of it. No more ads pop up.
However, my security center service is disabled. I went into services, security center was disabled i enabled it and restarted computer it is now disabled again so i enabled it again an was able to turn security centre back on but after a minute or 2 it turns its self back off...

What can I do?  I tried sfc/scannow as well, but not finding any errors.

FYI, I'm running Windows 7 Pro SP1.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

There is a high likelihood you still have traces on your system.

I would try using Kaspersky's TDSSKiller (free download) and run it in safe mode.
http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208283363

I would look at the windows error logs to see if there is any error messages regarding the the security center service or service dependencies that are not behaving.

Right click on Computer>Manage> Expand "Event Viewer" > Select "System" and examine the error messages. That might help you get to the bottom of the issue.

BlackViper has a .reg file that will reset all your services to their default start states:
http://www.blackviper.com/Windows_7/registry.htm (scroll down the page a bit)

Lets start there for now, if nothing works... I have a few more steps.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you are hopefully clean, I would do a system restore to a time before you became infected. That will not affect any documents you have, but will turn back the time on your registry, which was probably affected by the virus, and allow the service to start again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I disable system restore in the first place, no restore point :(