# window security center can't be started

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, virus, malware

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit (x64)

Infection date and initial symptoms:
Last week, I noticed when I right click on a red flag in "Window Security Alert" icon, it pop out a message "Security Center Service is turned off", So, I tried to click turn on now but the error message keep showing"Security Center service can't be started".

I think that the reason is my browser is infected with some malicious software. My antivirus scanned for two malicious software and I had deleted it. So I open the window defender and click on full scan but nothing was found. Then, I type on services.msc to check for security center of its status type and I found it was disabled. So, I click on properties and select automatic delayed start. However the problem haven't solved after I reboot my computer.

[image]

Here is the result after I type the command for System File Checker (SFC)

[image]

Can you please help?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/318265/windows-security-center-service-cant-be-started?rq=1

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/300872/security-center-wont-start-after-a-malware-attack?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but it still haven't solved my problem.  I had scanned and removed the virus but nothing was found after I reboot my machine. How to restore the missing "Security Center" service in Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: I think I got the Google Redirect virus now in Mozilla browser and my devices and printers cannot open.

Comment: Reinstall Windows 7 or fully remove the infection.  If you can't enable the service it's likely your still infected with malware.

Comment: If you use a third-party anti-malware suite, it will turn off Windows Defender. That is a *good* thing, since two AV suites operating would cause contention issues.

Comment: Thanks，I solved my problem. I've spending a lot of times to scan my computer. Finally, I found it is a behavior blocking and web threats that cause this problems. The window security center and devices and printers works normally now.

Comment: I also found that the protocol has been modified because of a Trojan or spyware.
Type:
Http/https protocol modified

Description:
Repairs http/https protocol, restores to system default settings, repairs IE browser errors caused by broken protocol.

Scan Engine:
System Repair Engine

Suggestion:
Restore defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a command prompt as Administrator and type in sfc /scannow and hit enter. This will repair Windows Files and may or may not repair the Security Center. If that does not help or sfc is not able to start, reboot into safe mode (restart windows and hit f8 until you see a menu pop up) and try it again.

However, I would recommend that you safe your data and reinstall windows completely. Your computer may be clean now but it is obvious that your system is misconfigured, missing system files and such. This makes it an easy target for other malicious malware and it will not take long until you get infected again.

Comment: Thanks Steven, but after I scanned in cmd.exe and type sfc /scannow it showed the message Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations. Do you have any other solutions without reinstalling the window 7?